# Iterate through array and select every 2 elements

Tags: ruby

Here's my code below:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
multiplie_array = [array[0]*2, array[1], array[2]*2, array[3], array[4]*2, array[5]]
=> [2, 2, 6, 4, 10, 6]
```

So the result is good, but imagine this code for an array composed of 1 million element.

My question : How do you iterate through an array according to a specific index and then multiply ?

Comment: Did you tried anything? StackOverflow is not a 'Write some code for me' service, we are here to help you with advice or try helping you debug some code.

Comment: @adi is correct "StackOverflow is not a 'Write some code for me' service". But apparently the TARK has did some work on his own and he attached his trial to the question so that should be fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by [mapping](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-map) your array, [with an index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map.with_index { |el,i| i.even? ? el * 2 : el }
#  => [2, 2, 6, 4, 10, 6]
```

Every element at an even index will get multiplied by `2`, every odd element will be left untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways you could do that without an index.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

**#1**

```
tf = [2, 1].cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: [2, 1]:cycle>
arr.map { |el| el*tf.next }
  #=> [2, 2, 6, 4, 10, 6]
```

See [Array#cycle](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-cycle).

**#2**

```
n = 1
arr.map { |el| (n = 3-n)*el }
  #=> [2, 2, 6, 4, 10, 6]
```